# SELECT records WHERE rows have difference on a specific column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table `campaign_data`. I need to select the `customer_id` where in the campaign there is difference in tariff. How can i do that with MySQL query. Here is some sample data.

[SQL Fiddle Schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48b6e/1)

```
| CAMPAIGN_ID | CUSTOMER_ID |    CAMPAIGN_NAME | TARIFF |
---------------------------------------------------------
|           1 |           1 |         Richmond |    100 |
|           2 |           1 | Sutton Coldfield |     75 |
|           3 |           1 |           Putney |    100 |
|           4 |           1 |     Kentish Town |    100 |
|           5 |           1 |           Woking |    100 |
|           6 |           2 |         Chiswick |     90 |
|           7 |           2 |           Ealing |    100 |
|           8 |           2 |           Camden |    100 |
|           9 |           3 |          Croydon |     75 |
|          10 |           3 |         Croydon1 |    100 |
|          11 |           3 |          Archway |    100 |
|          12 |           4 |          Ealing0 |    100 |
|          13 |           4 |         Ealing01 |    100 |
|          14 |           4 |         Ealing02 |    100 |
|          15 |           4 |        Chingford |    100 |
|          16 |           4 |      chingford01 |    100 |
```

Now as you can see customer id 1 , and 3 has different tariffs. I want to select them and leave the customer id 4 because it has campaigns with same tariffs.

Desired Output

```
| CUSTOMER_ID |
---------------
|           1 |
|           2 |
|           3 |
```

For clearification you can see customer 1 has 5 records. If in his 5 records the tariff is same (100) i want to avoid but if the tariff is not some as 4 records have 100 and one has 75, i want to select.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT customer_id, count(DISTINCT tariff) as tariffs 
FROM campaign_data 
GROUP BY customer_id 
HAVING tariffs > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  customer_id,
  tariff
from campaign_data
group by customer_id
having sum(tariff)/count(tariff) <> tariff;
```

Comment: thanks @Yordi that gave me good learning! there were spell mistakes though!

Comment: this is wrong :) , i have think about it but its wrong ,what about this tariff , 100,99,101 ? it will be equal tariff :)

Answer (score 1):

you looking for this maybe

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM campaign_data 
GROUP BY customer_id 
HAVING count(DISTINCT tariff) > 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48b6e/31